# Question about the exact definition of a Groebner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis

So the definition I learned is that a set $G = \{g_1,...g_t\}$ is a Groebner basis for an ideal I if $<Lt(g_1),...Lt(g_t)> = <LT(I)>$

However I'm not sure if it also requires the set G to be a normal basis for the ideal I. In most sources I read they don't mention this is required, but isisf this is the case I run into problems with reduced Groebner bases.

For example (taken from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms, paragraph 2.7 example 1) take I = $<x^3-2xy,x^2y-2y^2+x>$ with graded lexicographic order. This has reduced Groebner basis $H = \{x^2,xy,y^2-x/2\}$

However then why would $J = \{x^2,xy,y^2\}$ not be a reduced Groebner basis too? J has the exact same leading terms as H, so should satisfy the definition just as well. However this logic makes a mistake somewhere since reduced Groebner basis are unique, but I don't see where.

Comment: $J$ is not a generating set for $I$: $y^2\notin I$ as is plain from inspection of the Groebner basis $H$.

Comment: So for J to be a Groebner basis for I it is required that J generates I, so the definition I assumed in the first paragraph is incomplete?

Comment: Could you please quote **exactly** the definition of Groebner basis given by Cox et al.

Comment: Definition 5. Fix a monomial order on the polynomial ring $k[x_1,..., x_n]$. A finite
subset $G = \{g_1,..., g_t\}$ of an ideal I ⊆ $k[x_1,..., x_n]$ different from $\{0\}$ is said to
be a Gröbner basis (or standard basis) if
$<Lt(g_1),...Lt(g_t)> = <LT(I)>$

Comment: Well, there we are: "a finite subset $G$ ... of an ideal $I$".

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh thank you somehow in my brain though that was automatically reached, that makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms* by Cox, Little & O'Shea, it is required that
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\lt}{lt}\bigl\langle \lt(g_1),\dots,\lt(g_t)\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle \lt(I)\bigr\rangle, $$
and it is proved that a Groebner basis of $I$ generates the ideal $I$ (chapter 2, §5, Corollary 6).

Comment: But then where is my mistake in the reasoning I used in paragraphs 3 and 4 to obtain another reduced Groebner basis? They have the same leading terms thus both satisfy this condition so I can't find the mistake

Comment: Are  you sure $y^2\in I$?